# How to update a damped track bone constraint?

Tags: game-engine, armature, constraints

I'm implementing a bone constraint for a racing game, to make the characters in the audience look in the direction of the leading car. I have it working in the character file (the character's head is following the empty target position) and when I lilbload/add the characters (and parent the targets to the car)  the heads are correctly oriented. But as the game progresses, the bones never update, the characters heads stay in the same place as I move the target around...? And no error or warning in the console output...?

I made sure my target is correctly libloaded and parented to the real moving object (the car) with:

```
for people in logic.getCurrentScene().objects['People'].childrenRecursive:
    render.drawLine(people.worldPosition, target.worldPosition, [1,0,0])
```

And sure enough, a line is connecting each character to the moving object. The target works.

What I tried :

- An "always" sensor (w/ or w/o "pulse") to an "armature" actuator, running either "run armature" (?) or "set target" or both
- An "always" sensor (w/ or w/o "pulse") to a python module running `logic.getCurrentScene().objects.get('Armature').update()` at every single tick
- Replace the "Damped Track" bone constraint with a "track to"
- Removing all animations in the character file in case a keyframe is preventing the bone from moving

But nope, the characters head do-not-move as I move (applyForce) the car. Is there something like applyConstraint that I must use?

Comment: why not just use track to logic brick? it's simpler than python (I my mind)

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the numerous things that I tried...

Comment: so.. you tried [edit object]>[track to] ? and what was the result?

Comment: Well, right now it does not work, which confuses me because last time I tried it rotated the whole armature... The thing about bones and logic bricks, is that the whole skeleton seem to share the bricks..? I mean, When I select the belly bone (in "Pose" mode) I can see the bricks connected to the head bone..? Another thing: If I want to do anything with my character (like set its worldOrientation to this of its "position" target) I *have to* wire it to an action actuator, even an empty (0 keys) one.

Comment: Obviously I'm doing it wrong. Do you know an exemple of a Mesh+Armature libloaded in a scene, with a "track to" that works and updates in realtime? I'm really lost here, it's been days!

Comment: @xaccrocheur it could be that other logic bricks are messing this up since there is no logic brick for each bone it is for the whole armature object !  , also try parenting an object to the bone (not the armature) to see if the bone is following (it could deformation problem ),

Comment: But I made numerous tests, sometimes with just a 10 faces polygon with only 2 bones, and no "other logic bricks"! No, I'm missing something *big* about libloading an object and its armature with a damped track constraint.

Comment: @Monster can you please take a look at this

Comment: @chebhou Monster already provided [guidance on that](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?365864-How-to-use-playAction()-on-libloaded-objects&p=2841751&viewfull=1#post2841751) (but thanks for the attention, really nice of you) he had bad news (no constraints on libloaded objects) but also a workaround (that I did not have [the time to test](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/go-go-speed-racer/) yet).