# How to animate armature in blender/python?

Tags: python, armature

I tried to animate simple bones with python, keyframes are inserted in timeline but nothing happens,
Partially this question is copy-paste of that one (sorry) but I didn't find answer there

[Controlling armature through python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2256/controlling-armature-through-python)

```
import bpy

import math
import mathutils
from mathutils import Euler

rig = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
bone = rig.pose.bones['Bone.00']
print("temp", rig)

rot = math.radians(5)
bone.rotation_euler = Euler((rot, rot, rot))
bone.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame=1)

rot2 = math.radians(100)
bone.rotation_euler = Euler((rot2, rot2,rot2 ))
bone.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame =50)
```

[image]

UPDATE:
After running few times and removing previous keyframe animation is still cached somewhere how to clear it ?

[image]

Comment: By default bone rotation mode is set to Quaternion. Either chage it to Euler or use `bone.rotation_quaternion`

Comment: @JayReigns Thanks!